# what are the hard disk drive file format supported by Oracle VM Manager?

Tags: oracle, azure, virtual-machine, vhd, vdi

Hi I am currtently working on migrating OVM to Azure VHD.So need to know that what are the hard disk drive file format supported by Oracle VM Manager.

And is there is any tool which takes care of converting OVM file to azure VHD ?

Answer (score 0):

I have oftenly used the VBoxManage.exe  tool from VirtualBox installation.
It support many files format.
the command to use should be the following:
VBoxManage.exe clonehd --format vhd  /VMs/VM1/disk1.vmdk

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks Giova and Is there is any performance issue during this migration ?

Comment: What type of performance are you referring to? The big resource used during the process is I/O and possibly network